# ASP.NET server side form validation + jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

ASP.NET 4.0 site

What could be a better practice for using both ASP.NET server side form validation + jQuery client validation? I found that if using  control with ASP.NET form validator controls, the TextBox tag will be populated as  in HTML with a long ID. Will this long ID causing any trouble when using jQuery validation lib due to the ID is not easily predictable? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .Net 4, you can use the new [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) for your controls. Also, you can use markup: `'<%= Mytextbox.ClientID %>'` in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the (asp.net usercontrol) [ClientId](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) property on controls to ensure the id of the control on the clientside